# how can I filter peaks less than specific duration?

Tags: matlab

I used matlab function `findpeaks.m` to find peaks which its absolute amplitude is bigger than 4.0, but I need to find which the peak duration is less than 7 second. But I think `findpeaks.m` have only minimum option not maximum option. And also I want to find full width, not FWHM. any help?

[image]

this if one of example that i have to analyze.

Comment: What is your data? give an example

Comment: just simple descrete value of eeg

Comment: I don't know what is eeg like many other people. By giving example, you may increase your chance of getting an answer from people who are not specifically in your field.

Comment: Why not pass a low pass filter first, so that you can filter out smaller ones?

Comment: I think low pass filter can filter out only for frequency, but I have to filter peaks that amplitude is higher than limitation, so is it possible with 'butter' or  other codes?

Comment: @smttsp it is a data consists of 500Hz time x values and measured voltage y values for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use MinPeakWidth (Matlab2017a) as described in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com